# DIfference between a static final field and an instance final field initialized at declaration when accessed through an object

Tags: java, static, field, constants, final

- First example

  ```
  public class MyClass {
      final int x = 2;
  }
  ```

  **x** is

  1. **final** which means it can never be set after initialization.
  2. **Initialized at declaration** which means it can't have a different value assigned to it later (even in the constructor).
  3. **fixed** (regardless of the instance) because its value can't be changed in the constructor (or anywhere else really).
- Second example

  ```
  public class MyOtherClass {
      static final int x = 3;
  }
  ```

  **x** is

  1. **final** which means it can never be set after initialization.
  2. **Initialized at declaration** which means it can't have a different value assigned to it later.
  3. a **static** field and the value will always remain the same regardless of the instance.
  4. **constant** because it is both *static* and *final*.

My questions are

What are the differences between both? (excluding creation time)

Am i missing something?

Comment: This is my first question so, feel free to comment on the style and if i can improve it.

Comment: If you initialise a final variable at declaration time then it should probably be static...

Comment: One potential difference is a `static final` primitive is not used during runtime. The compiler would 've replaced all occurances of it with the value during compilation making it more optimised.

Comment: @Codebender: that applies to the non-`static` variable as well, and even for local variables. *All* `final` variables which are initialized with a compile-time constant are compile-time constants and never accessed by ordinary Java code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The differences between `x` in `MyClass` and `MyOtherClass` are:

- the first can only be accessed via a `MyClass` instance and there can be multiple copies of the constant.
- the second can be accessed without `MyOtherClass` instance and only one copy can exist.

In your example, there is no practical difference<sup>1</sup> between having one or multiple instances of the constant.  However consider this:

```
public class YetAnotherClass {
    final int x;

    public YetAnotherClass(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

... which shows how an instance constant can have different values in different instances.

---

<sup>1 - That is an overstatement.  First, `static final int x = 3;` is declaring a compile-time constant, and a compile-time constant can be used in a switch case expression, where a non-compile-time constant can't.  Second the non-static version of the constant will occupy space in each and every instance of `MyClass`. Finally, there will be differences in behaviour if you are daft enough to try to change the constants using reflection.  (Just don't do it ...)</sup>

Comment: Could escape analysis / JIT optimizations cache value of x when only `final int x` is used?

Comment: Possibly.  However, the code would still need to work if the constant was accessed using reflection, so the field would probably need to be allocated anyway.

Comment: makes sense. This would then apply to `static final int` as well..

Comment: In the `static final` case, if the constant qualifies as a compile-time constant, the optimization is performed (in part) by the bytecode compiler.

Comment: It seems to be an often overlooked thing of the Java programming language, maybe because some tutorials get it wrong as well, but there is no difference between `static` variables and non-`static` variables when it comes to compile-time constant behavior. *All* `final` variables, which are initialized with a compile-time constant, are compile-time constants as well and never read by ordinary Java code. This applies to local variables as well and *yes*, that means you can use local variables in `case` clauses of a `switch` statement, if they are compile-time constants.

Comment: @Holger - Yes.  See footnote 1.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Although `final`, the JVM does not make any optimizations or assumptions, so each instance of the class will have an instance of `x`. If you declare the member `static`, each instance of the class will share the same instance of `x` because it's statically allocated. Moreover, as written (`x` has package visibility), other classes can potentially access `x` statically, i.e., without having an instance of the class available.

Answer (score 1):

If you create multiple instances of both type of classes then,

In First scenario all object of `MyClass` would have own `final x` field.

Where as in second scenario all object of `MyOtherClass` would have points to one `final x` class field as because it is static in nature.

Comment: I think in second case, the object's of `MyOtherClass` dont point to the `static final x` at all. It belongs to the class and not the object.

Comment: yes, dats right, I tried to portray the same.

Answer (score 1):

Difference : 
Static belongs to class So You can access it without any instance of the class and hence only one copy of it.

While for accessing second one you need instance of an class to access it so you can have as many copy of non static final Object as it belongs to Object.

You can Verify with Byte Code:
For Static

```
Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: return
```

For Non-Static Final

```
Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: aload_0
         5: iconst_2
         6: putfield      #2                  // Field x:I
         9: return
      LineNumberTable:
```

As you can see it's has *putfield* Which sets the value of the field identified in objectref (a reference to an object)

Comment: It baffles me that people think that it is a good idea to explain the Java language to beginners by showing them bytecode sequences.

Comment: @StephenC - defending this answer.. This answer could be useful for others (intermediate level?) as well :).. Not just the OP..

Comment: @StephenC It's just for everyone :)

Comment: No it is not for everyone.  It is for people who understand bytecodes.  That precludes beginners, like the OP (I expect).  Besides, the OP is asking about differences **excluding creation time**, and surely this is about creation time ...

Comment: "While for accessing second one"
Second one is the static one. but, I get your point.
I also as mentioned by @StephanC do not understand bytecode. but, it might be useful for others.